# How do I make an object destructible?

Tags: unity, gameobject

How do I make one of my objects break into random pieces? I've tried Add-Ons, Blender, and a few other things that I can't remember of the top of my head.

Comment: Could you show what the object looks like and how it should break?

Comment: It would also help if you elaborate on what you tried in Blender & with Add-Ons; generally speaking, what steps did you take, what results did you get & in what ways did they fail to work out?

Comment: if you want to make the object shatters, this 5 minutes video will get you started https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EgNV0PWVaS8

Answer (score 1):

You don't necessarily have to make the object itself destructible.  Instead, you can create a number of separate models of "pieces" of your object.

If you have the object blowing up, then you can draw an explosion effect, remove/hide the original object, and then spawn the various pieces being thrown out randomly.  Each is a separate and unique new object.

If the object is going to break in a more natural way, then you can do a variation of the same idea, but have the pieces all spawn basically in their original location if the object was assembled.  Assuming you've got physics active, the pieces will then fall and tumble as they would normally.

Comment: I know that the issue is that every single way of making smaller peices of the model is either broken, broken, or crashes unity

Comment: @MarineRec You are obviously doing something wrong, but unless you show us what you've tried so far, it's hard to tell on what step you are stuck. Without providing these details, people will just suggest solutions you've already tried, and this will not lead anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking to do is called Fracture Meshes. Unreal has these built in but Unity does not. You'll probably want to fork up some cash as doing this manually is quite the task. A quick outline of the theory to give you an idea of why you might just want a library for this:

A material experiences stress and you can determine this via propagating forces of elements (triangles). Each triangle can experience a stress and pass that stress to a neighboring element. Stress can be broken up into two parts, tensile and compressive. Compressive implies objects pushing into eachother, tensile involves objects pulling apart. You need to compute the tensile stress at each point where the object CAN break (whether it's every vertex, or you split your mesh into pre-fractured pieces and just check those chunks). Then if your tensile stress is greater than the tensile strength of the material, split the mesh and cause a fracture. The math behind this is not fun, and you can fake a FAIR amount if it. For example, stress is proportional to force, so you could have some very faked system where you measure the distance from the force impact point and the further the distance the less that part of the material feels that force. This would be a HUGE estimate but could yield some results.

Here's a resource that covers the basics (if you can call them that) and extends upon them for perfectly fractured meshes. This is far overkill for a video game, but DOES introduce basic concepts

[[Zhu Bridson Greif] Simulating Rigid Body Fracture with Surface Meshes](https://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/zhu-siggraph2015-surfacefracture.pdf)